# I am a 10th grader and aspire to become like you guys

Tags: soft-question, education

People say my idols are Messi and Ronaldo(no hate) but I dont know why I am attracted to Physics and Math.It always amazes me, this is just a dumb question which i suppose is gonna be closed by midnight today but can someone teach me physics? I would love to and also do questions he/she gives me, it will be like a free trial for me as a student and you as a teacher. Once again, even though this is closed, just know that I love you guys and you are what I aspire to be one day.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Comment: If you don't, I will edit this and add an actual question @TobiasFünke

Comment: Asking for "someone to teach you physics" isn't a good question for this site - which aims for one-off textual responses, not some sort of long-term teacher-student relationship. But you can ask for recommendation of resources - videos, books, and so on. If you do, you'll need to say something about what you already know - did you learn any physics in school? What did you learn in math (e.g., derivatives? integrals? does this ring a bell?). Without much math experience, I would recommend to start with popular physics books, not full-scale university-level lectures or textbooks.

Comment: @NadavHar'El I know 10th grade Math and Physics well and I think I'll learn calculus next year in class 11th

Comment: See Gerard 't Hooft's website, https://www.goodtheorist.science/. This is in my opinion the best collection of resources. Add to this David Tong's lecture notes collection (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/teaching.html), which are an excellent pedagogical resource, from statistical mechanics to gauge theory and supersymmetry in field theories.

Comment: @VaibhavK i viewed the cambridge website but unfortunately i dont know the math to undertake newtonian mechanics etc

Comment: The mathematics in Newtonian mechanics taught in school is usually very simply (basic vector calculus), but it is a part of classical mechanics, where you deal with more formal definitions of dynamics, such as Lagrangian mechaniccs and so on. Learning mathematics shouldn't be something you need advice for, since there are many places on the internet where you can learn them at a good level. Pop-sci books are _not_ recommended. I think anyone can make sense of the fundamental mathematics with proper time and effort.

Comment: @VaibhavK well bhai, As a class 10th student I dont know anything I suppose you understand as you are of the same Country as me

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to learn physics is from books. Analyze and select your current level in physics and search books for the topic you want to learn or understand in physics. First of all,if you have knowledge of physics of high school level then  I recommend you to read ['Feynman lectures'](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/index.html) where you can understand almost all the topics of physics which will help in strengthen of your basic foundation of physics. From there , you can choose any book of your interest and will be able to understand .
Sorry, but I am not able to give you guidance on maths.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Oh, no. Much better to learn physics in the real world. Make telescopes, microscopes, spectroscopes, and examine the world with them. Experiment with electronics, levers, turbines, whatever you're interested in. And, of course, read books to learn to do these things and to understand what you're seeing, but don't imagine that mere stories about physics are actual physics. You won't find the basic foundations in books: they are everywhere around you.

Comment: Note that Feynman started out tinkering with radios.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in 9th grade I had a similar question as you. I wanted someone to teach me advanced physics. It turns out that there are people that can teach you advanced physics. You just have to find them, and they are in the form of books. You have to be specific on what you exactly want to learn.

But if you want a personal tutor to teach you/guide you through physics, then I can help you. You can reach out to be via my email, which can be found in a link through my YouTube channel.

This is definitely not a question for this site, but I do appreciate the “naive” courage to ask anyway. Good luck with physics!

Comment: Sir, your YouTube Channel's name please?

Comment: It can be found in my profile. It’s fermion physics

Comment: Sir, your channel is great, but I dont think that the Math I know and what I am as of now I have the capability to even live in the same world as you do, you are of course very successful in the field of physics and are what I want to be